# Angular-cli installs but doesnt start new project: package install failed

Tags: angular

when running ng new hello-world command it shows package installation failed.
Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 ia32
[image: package install failed]

Comment: Did you check your log file? What describes there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ti uninstall angular cli and install it

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli npm cache verify # if npm version is < 5 then use 
`npm cache clean
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest npm install
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/README.md)